# PowerShell object member is null from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run `Get-NetAdapter -Physical` from C#. If I run it from PS itself the resulting table has InterfaceDescription and MacAddress columns with meaningful values, however doing this in C#:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("Get-NetAdapter");
    ps.AddParameter("Physical");
    var results = ps.Invoke();
[...error checking here...]
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
[...null check here...]
        var name = result.Members["InterfaceDescription"].Value;
        var mac = result.Members["MacAddress"].Value;
    }
}
```

The second line in the foreach throws a NullReferenceException at the left-hand side of `.Value`. If I change `Members` to `Properties` the result is the same. `name` is fine. I've also tried using `dynamic` to get to the members but that doesn't seem to work either. How can I get to the object that I can obtain in PowerShell through `thing.MacAddress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this because "MacAddress" is a ScriptProperty:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Get-Member -Name MacAddress | fl *


TypeName   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter
Name       : MacAddress
MemberType : ScriptProperty
Definition : System.Object MacAddress {get=$out = ""
                       if (($this.NetworkAddresses -ne $null) -and
                           ($this.NetworkAddresses.length -ge 1))
                       {
                         $MacAddress = $this.NetworkAddresses[0];
                       }
                       if($MacAddress -ne $null)
                       {
                           for($i = 0; $i -lt $MacAddress.Length; )
                           {
                               $out += $MacAddress[$i++];
                               if($i -eq $MacAddress.Length)
                               {
                                 break;
                               }
                               $out += $MacAddress[$i++];
                               if ($i -lt $MacAddress.Length)
                               {
                                 $out += '-';
                               }
                           }
                       }
                       $out;set=param($newValue)
                       $MacAddress = $newValue -replace '(:|-)'
                       $this.NetworkAddresses = $MacAddress;}
```

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776105/how-to-get-scriptproperty-values-of-psobject-properties-in-c), if you just pipe the results to `Select-Object *`, the ScriptProperty will be evaluated in the PowerShell runspace and returned as a Note instead.